# MongoDB: how to use unique and optional index in mongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my field in my Mongoose schema:

```
var userSchema = moongoose.Schema({
  ...
  customer_id: {
    type: Number,
    trim: true
  }
  ...
}, {
  timestamps: true
});
```

I want this field to be unique, and also accepts from clients things like `""`, `null` or `undefined`.

1) I tried this:

```
customer_id: {
  type: Number,
  trim: true,
  index: {
    unique: true,
    partialFilterExpression: {customer_id: {$type: 'number'}}
  }
}
```

2) Also this:

```
customer_id: {
  type: Number,
  trim: true,
  index: {
    unique: true,
    partialFilterExpression: {customer_id: {$exists: true}}
  }
}
```

3) And this:

```
customer_id: {
  type: Number,
  trim: true,
  unique: true,
  sparse: true
}
```

These don't work.

I reset my collection every time between each test, and still have a 409 Conflict error when I add a second customer.

EDIT: Documents which should match, without conflict (currently conflicting): I have a first customer with id `customer_id: 11111`. Now I want to add another customer, who can have `customer_id: 22222`, `customer_id: ''` or `customer_id: null`, but not `customer_id: 11111`.

MongoDB shell / db version: 3.4.4
Mongoose: 4.9.7

Any idea ?

Comment: Could you update your question to show two documents that should be allowed but are resulting in a conflict?

Comment: have you tried creating index on customer_id key? Like db.users.createIndex({customer_id:1},{ unique:true,partialFilterExpression: {customer_id: {$type: 'number'}} } ?

Comment: @Astro: I didn't use any mongo shell command like your ones, I use Mlab coupled with Heroku and don't have all accesses (yet) to use Mongo shell
Or are you saying that this line must be implemented in the code ?

Comment: yes, you can create such index from code as well

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't show what's conflicting that you don't want to conflict.

Comment: @Astro: I'm not sure about when to use it in the code

Comment: @JohnnyHK: The examples I gave are all conflicting, I wasn't very clear sorry, will update

Comment: Sounds like a simple `unique: true` index is all you need. When you say you "reset" the collection each time, are you dropping the collection? If you're just removing all the docs, the existing index will not be updated by mongoose.